# SQL Server Schedule Reset

Tags: sql-server

We recently had an issue where the date on a server was wound forward a few months and wasn't noticed.  We had a number of scheduled jobs run and now they're waiting until November until they run again.

I can't for the life of me find anywhere in SQL Server to change the Next Schedule Run Time.

Anyone have any idea or do I have to recreate each schedule again from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by editing the start date of each job. (open your job -> schedules -> edit schedule -> duration -> start date)

You could although have a look at the table `msdb..sysjobschedules` to check all schedules, it contains the columns `next_run_date` and `next_run_time` for your jobs.

Comment: I'd already spied the sysjobschedules table, altering those figures doesn't change the schedule.  The Start Date change was perfect.

Comment: Good to know thanks. But i really wonder why it is there then